# v-if and v-else not working in nested v-for list

Tags: vue.js

I have a nested v-for of item

```html
<div class="media" v-for="(comment, parentIndex) in adminComments">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="media" v-for="(answer, index) in comment">
      <label class="control-label upload" v-if="comment.data===''">
        <input class="file-upload" type="file" @change="uploadFile($event, parentIndex)">
        Upload file
      </label>

     <label class="control-label upload" v-else>
       <input class="file-upload" type="file" @change="uploadFile($event, parentIndex)">
      {{comment.name}}
     </label>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is basically it, my adminComments is an array of objects and these objects have some attrs, including name, however, this name is changed with a function after the file is uploaded as well as a "loading" attribute to change an icon class, however, none of them is rendering.
As i read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key) the labels should be rendered well, however, this is not happening. I know that my comment object is indeed working because I also have a textarea with a `v-model="comment.response"`. What could be wrong? I have done the same before and it has worked but in a single v-for and not in a nested list. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some example of `adminComments` data.

Comment: Try using keys with `v-for`

Comment: Does `(answer, index) in comment` imply that `comment` is an array?